# Algorithm to compute solution set of single simple equation with two variables

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Suppose I have a simple equation of the form:

```
7x + 4y = n
```

where n is chosen by us and x, y and n are all positive integers. This is the only equation which is given to us. Among the possible solutions we need the solution (x,y) in which x is the smallest. e.g.

```
7x + 4y = 14, then (2, 0) is the solution
7x + 4y = 15, then (1, 2) is the solution
7x + 4y = 32, then (4, 1) and (0, 8) are the possible solutions,
of which (0, 8) is the correct solution
```

I would like to design an algorithm to calculate it in the least possible running time. The current algorithm which I have in mind goes something like this:

```
Given an input n
Calculate max(x) = n/7
for i = 0 to max(x)
    If the equation 7*i + 4*y = n holds
        return value of i and y
    else
        continue
```

This algorithm, I presume, can have a running time of upto O(n) in worst case behaviour. Is there some better algorithm to compute the solution?

Comment: You say `If the equation 7*i + 4*y = n holds` i you get from the loop but what is y?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on X and Y?  If so, binary search your way to success.

Comment: You might want to read about [linear integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integral_linear_programs). Your problem is definetly a specific instance of the generalized problem, but I am curious if there is an efficient solution for the simplified problem you are facing.

Comment: @msam Since we know the value of i and n, we just check if there is an integer y which satisfies the equation for the given i and n.

Comment: @amit Yup i will read the link and get back to you. If there is some generalzed solution then nothing like it :)

Comment: Also note, your suggested algorithm is [pseudo-polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), so it still not enough to tell if the problem is indeed NP-Hard or not.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Obviously X and Y cannot exceed n/7 and n/4 in this case

Comment: @Th0rndike I am learning building up my algorithmic intuition and was implementing the code for the algorithm I suggested, just wondering if there exists any better algorithm than the one proposed by me

Comment: may I point out that if you want to include (2,0) or (0,8) as valid answers then the constraint on x and y should be set as non-negative as opposed to positive (integers).

Comment: that means you need another loop in there with `Calculate max(y) = n/4`

Comment: @msam no we wont, since we either have to run the for loop upto max(x) or max(y)

Comment: This asks for solution for [CodeChef May 2012 contest problem DIVPAIR](http://www.codechef.com/MAY12/problems/DIVPAIR) :-(

Comment: @Betlista I've [raised the issue on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131331) should you want to comment further

Comment: @Betlista Agreed, this is something similar to what you point out (although the codechef problem, if I understood it correctly, involves a lot more calculations as compared to mine). But don't you think a person can search or copy any other person's code if d entire point was to solve a question and get it over with instead of learning. AFAIK, even CodeChef reveals the code of all the participants after the end of the competition. The reason I posted the question, inspite of having an algorithm in my mind, was to get a clear understanding of the best algorithm behind solving linear equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us consider the more general problem

- For two coprime positive integers `a` and `b`, given a positive integer `n`, find the pair `(x,y)` of nonnegative integers such that `a*x + b*y = n` with minimal `x`. (If there is one. There need not be, e.g. `7*x + 4*y = 5` has no solution with nonnegative `x` and `y`.)

Disregarding the nonnegativity for the moment, given any solution

```
a*x0 + b*y0 = n
```

*all* solutions have the form `(x0 - k*b, y0 + k*a)` for some integer `k`. So the remainder of `x` modulo `b` and of `y` modulo `a` is an invariant of the solutions, and we have

```
a*x ≡ n (mod b), and b*y ≡ n (mod a)
```

So we need to solve the equation `a*x ≡ n (mod b)` - the other one follows.

Let `0 < c` be an integer with `a*c ≡ 1 (mod b)`. You find it for example by the extended Euclidean algorithm, or (equivalently) the continued fraction expansion of `a/b` in O(log b) steps. Both algorithms naturally yield the unique `c < b` with that property.

Then the minimal candidate for `x` is the remainder `x0` of `n*c` modulo `b`.

The problem has a solution with nonnegative `x` and `y` if and only if `x0*a <= n`, and then `x0` is the minimal nonnegative `x` appearing in any solution with nonnegtaive `x` and `y`.

Of course, for small `a` and `b` like 7 and 4, the brute force is no slower than calculating the inverse of `a` modulo `b`.

Answer (score 6):

We have

```
7(x-4)+4(y+7)=7x+4y
```

So if (x, y) is a solution, then (x-4,y+7) is also a solution. Hence if there is a solution then there is one with x<4. That's why you only need to test x=0..3 which runs in constant time.

This can be extended to any equation of the form ax+by=n, you only need to test x=0..b-1.

Comment: I think the equation can be changed.  What's there is just a sample.

Comment: If the equation is of the form ax+by=n then if there is a solution, then there is one with x < b.

Comment: Your idea is good and true (I think), but the answer is not informative enough. If I were you, I'd edit the answer and add more information and explanation. If you do so, some downvoters will probably un-downvote you. I +1ed it anyway, for leading the way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do it.

Comment: awesome solution (y)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out the Simplex method in the [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) book.  You can easily treat the C code like pseudo-code and make a java version.  The version of the simplex you want is the "constrained-simplex" which deals in positive values only.  The book is [available online for free](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).  Start with section 10.8 and read forward.

Comment: The Simplex method is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

O(n) :

```
y=n/4;
while((n-4y)%7!=0 && y!=0){
 y--;
}
x=(n-4y)/7;
```

Comment: why call floor on an integer? If n is an int, so is n/4. Also, for efficiency you should start with x because its upper bound is smaller.

Comment: i made it generic...there are some programming languages that convert divisions to float when the result is not an integer.

Comment: So you decided to make your code Java-specific in all aspects except the floor call.

Comment: ok you got me there.. I was not sure about the java behavior in this case because I use to develop in other languages too. Why are we discussing that instead of the algorithm? Why don't you write an answer yourself instead of criticizing other people's code?

Comment: Because what I would write is too close to what you already have there. I'm trying to motivate you to clean it up.